# Get JComboBox items string representation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I would like to obtain String representation of all the items contained in the JComboBox's model, how to do this?

```
    ListModel model = combobox.getModel();   
    for(int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) 
    {
        componentTexts.add( model.getElementAt( i ).toString() );
    }
```

This gives me different strings than combobox items - CellRenderer decides about the every combobox item's label text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rendered text is different than the toString() of the Object then you need to invoke the renderer directly.

The code might be something like:

```
ListCellRenderer renderer = comboBox.getRenderer();

Object child = comboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup)child;
JList list = popup.getList();

ListModel model = combobox.getModel();   
for(int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) 
{
    Object value = model.getElementAt(i);
    JLabel label = (JLabel)renderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, i, false, false);
    components.add( label.getText() );
}
```

Comment: model.getElement(i) should be model.getElementAt(i) - cant edit your post, cause SO says the edit must be at least 6 chars

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't in every case, because the CellRenderer does not return a String, but could return any JComponent it feels is appropriate to show, e.g. also an icon, an image, a color patch, or something more complex.

Still, you could try to access the combobox' CellRenderer and ask the cellRenderer for each Combobox item. This will return you a JComponent. If it is a JLabel (which it probably often is), you use the getText() method to extract the text. Something like:

```
if (component instance JLabel) {
    componentTexts.add ((JLabel) component).getText());
}
```